# Laravel-Permission - permission not found in artisan list - There are no commands defined in the "permission" namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

Hello Good Developers,

I am using `spatie:laravel-permissions` package in my application. I have identical code in local machine and production server.

**I am having a strange issue with my production environment.**

I cannot find `permission` in list of commands in `php artisan list`.

> When I execute `php artisan permission:cache-reset` it says

`There are no commands defined in the "permission" namespace.`

I tried  following things to fix this issue

- `Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,` in app.php
  providers
- `composer update`
- `composer dump-autoload`
- Cleared all config and application cache.
- deleted vendors directory and executed `composer install` to reinstall all the packages.

Still its not working.
However when I execute dump-autoload it says `Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-permission`

I am using `Laravel  5.7.28` and `spatie/laravel-permission:^2.5`

My Local system is working fine and I can see `permission` command in the list there.

Please help! I don't know where should I check now.

Comment: Execute `php_sapi_name()` from your CLI on production, what does it return?

Comment: how do I execute it? should I create a file and put this function there?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy when I execute this function it says `cgi-fcgi`

Comment: Then that's the problem. Right there. PHP is not returning `cli` so the `->isRunningInConsole()` check is failing, so the package can't register the commands.

Comment: Wonderfull! Earlier I was accessing SSH using `root` user and then was switching to domain user to run these commands, now when I am logging directly using domain user I can see `permission` command even I can see `CLI` in `SAPI name` as well.
@Ohgodwhy do you know why this magic happened?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. Many linux environments, many configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this command:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

If, for some reason, the command doesn't work, run these one by one:

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

After one of the above steps, if you are in production environment, run: **php artisan config:cache**